# Solve recursion $a_{n}=ba_{n-1}+cd^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ be constants with $b\neq d$. Let
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n} &=& ba_{n-1}+cd^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$
be a sequence for $n \geq 1$ with $a_{0}=0$. I want to find a *closed formula* for this recursion. (I only know the german term *geschlossene Formel* and translated it that way I felt it could be right. So if I got that wrong, please correct me)

First I wrote down some of the chains and I got
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n} &=& ba_{n-1}+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b\left(ba_{n-2}+cd^{n-2}\right)+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b\left(b\left(ba_{n-3}+cd^{n-3}\right)+cd^{n-2}\right)+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b\left(b\left(b\left(ba_{n-4}+cd^{n-4}\right)+cd^{n-3}\right)+cd^{n-2}\right)+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& \dots\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n}b^{k}cd^{n-k-1}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n}b^{k}cd^{n-\left(k+1\right)}
\end{eqnarray}$$

So I catched the structure in a serie. Now I am asking myself how to proceed. I took the liberty to have a little peek at what [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk=0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7Db%5E%7Bk%7D%20c%20d%5E%7Bn-%28k%2b1%29%7D) wood say to this serie. I hoped for inspiration and I got

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^{k} c d^{n-(k+1)} = (c (b^n-d^n))/(b-d)$$

How did this came to be? And more important: Is my approach useful?
Thank you in advance for any advice!

### Edit: My final Solution (recalculated)

$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n} &=& ba_{n-1}+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b\left(ba_{n-2}+cd^{n-2}\right)+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b\left(b\left(ba_{n-3}+cd^{n-3}\right)+cd^{n-2}\right)+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b\left(b\left(b\left(ba_{n-4}+cd^{n-4}\right)+cd^{n-3}\right)+cd^{n-2}\right)+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b^{4}a_{n-4}+b^{3}cd^{n-4}+b^{2}cd^{n-3}+bcd^{n-2}+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b^{5}a_{n-5}+b^{4}cd^{n-5}+b^{3}cd^{n-4}+b^{2}cd^{n-3}+bcd^{n-2}+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& b^{n}a_{0}+b^{n-1}c+\dots+b^{4}cd^{n-5}+b^{3}cd^{n-4}+b^{2}cd^{n-3}+cbd^{n-2}+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& \dots\\
&=& 0+b^{n-1}c+\dots+b^{4}cd^{n-5}+b^{3}cd^{n-4}+b^{2}cd^{n-3}+cbd^{n-2}+cd^{n-1}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^{k}cd^{n-1-k}\\
&=& cd^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^{k}d^{-k}\\
&=& cd^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)^{k}\\
&=& cd^{n-1}\frac{1-\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)^{n}}{1-\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)}\\
&=& cd^{n-1}\frac{1-\frac{b^{n}}{d^{n}}}{1-\frac{b}{d}}\\
&=& cd^{n-1}\frac{\frac{d^{n}-b^{n}}{d^{n}}}{\frac{d-b}{d}}\\
&=& cd^{n-1}\frac{d^{n}-b^{n}}{d^{n}}\cdot\frac{d}{d-b}\\
&=& \frac{c\left(d^{n}-b^{n}\right)}{d-b}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake somewhere. Mathematica finds me `RSolve[{a[n] == b a[n \[Minus] 1] + c d^(n - 1), a[0] == 0},
  a[n], n] ==> {{a[n] -> (c (b^n - d^n))/(b - d)}}`

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks for posting the solition of mathematica. I recalculated and got $(c\left(d^{n}-b^{n}\right))/(d-b)$. It is nearly the same, but I can't see where I miscalculated.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I see now, that it is actually the same. Just multiplyed it with (-1)/-1)... ^^"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}b^{k}cd^{n-(k+1)} = c d^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}b^{k}d^{-k}$. This the partial sum of a geometric series of ratio $b/d$, for which you probably know the formula. Now simplify.

Comment: Oh dear Loard, I was so blind. Of course it is the **Geometric progression** which is well known to every math student in the first semester. ^^ Thank you for pointing that out! I posted my solution under my question. Would you say it is right? I am worried, because my result differs from WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Aufwind You had an upper summation limit of $n$ at the first try that you fed into Wolfram Alpha. Change it to $n-1$ so that Wolfram Alpha has a chance.

Comment: @user9325: I see. I corrected it to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^{k} c d^{n-(k+1)} = (c (b^n-d^n))/(b-d)$. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6):

If you know how to solve linear recurences, this would simplify your computations:

\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n} &=& ba_{n-1}+cd^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
da_{n-1} &=& dba_{n-2}+cd^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}

and subtract....

Comment: Nice one. I like the fact that its quick.

Answer (score 6):

If $b=0$, then $a_n = cd^{n-1}$.

Now assume $b\neq 0$. You can first divide both sides of the equation by $b^n$, then you get
$$
\frac{a_n}{b^n} = \frac{a_{n-1}}{b^{n-1}} + \frac{cd^{n-1}}{b^n}
$$
Let $x_n = \frac{a_n}{b^n}$ and $q = \frac{d}{b}$, then $x_0 = a_0/b = 0$, $q\neq 1$, and we have
$$
x_n = x_{n-1} + (c/b)q^{n-1} \mbox{ or } x_n - x_{n-1} = (c/b)q^{n-1}
$$
Then we can apply the telescoping sum method,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x_n & = & x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})\\
    & = & (c/b)\sum_{i=1}^n q^{i-1}\\
    & = & (\frac{c}{b})(\frac{1-q^n}{1-q})
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So $$a_n = x_n b^n = (\frac{c}{b})(\frac{1-\frac{d^n}{b^n}}{1-\frac{d}{b}})b^n
 = \frac{c(b^n - d^n)}{b - d}$$

Answer (score 1):

Argh... use Wilf's techniques from "generatingfunctionology". Start defining:
$$
A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$
Also write:
$$
a_{n + 1} = b a_n + c d^n
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, add over $n \ge 0$:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} = b A(z) + c \frac{1}{1 - d z}
$$
Solve for $A(z)$, express as partial fractions. The resulting terms are of the forms:
$$
(1 - \alpha z)^{-m}
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-m}{n} (- \alpha)^n z^n
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} \alpha^n z^n
$$
Note that:
$$
\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} 
  = \frac{(n + m - 1) (n + m - 2) \ldots (n + 1)}{(m - 1)!}
$$
This is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m - 1$.
$$
$$